# How to Inject JavaScript in WebView?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Please I need help with injecting JavaScript in a WebView in C#.

I'm trying to come up with a WebView that responds to a click event (NOTE: The html from the WebView is not mine, and it is dynamically generated). Unfortunately, a click event is not part of what it responds to according to [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx#methods). So I'm left with the option of responding to events of html elements from the WebView. So far, I found this code on [saramgsilva](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2015/windows-store-apps-invoke-scriptnotify-event-when-we-click-a-button-inside-a-webview/):

```
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
     {
         "var signButton=document.getElementById(\"MyButton\");" +
         "if (signButton.addEventListener) {" +
             "signButton.addEventListener(\"click\", MyButtonClicked, false);" +
         "} else {" +
             "signButton.attachEvent('onclick', MyButtonClicked);" +
         "}  " +
         "function MyButtonClicked(){" +
             " window.external.notify('%%' + location.href);"+
          "}"
     });
```

I modified it to get this in my code:

```
await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
         {
             "var bodyEl=document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\");" +
             "if (bodyEl[0].addEventListener) {" +
                 "bodyEl[0].addEventListener(\"click\", VideoClicked, false);" +
             "} else {" +
                 "bodyEl[0].attachEvent('onclick', VideoClicked);" +
             "}  " +
             "function VideoClicked(){" +
                 " window.external.notify('VideoClick');"+
              "}"
         });
```

And this code is supposed to respond to the call window.external.notify('VideoClick'):

```
private void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        var url = e.Value;
    }
```

When execution gets here, I expect url to contain 'VideoClick', this method was never called when I stepped through the code.

The code was supposed to insert JavaScript but, Unfortunately, I'm NOT getting an exception and it's not working the way I expect, and it seems [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) is meant to call a JavaScript function only.

I also tried to use AllowedScriptNotifyUris method in the example on [ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227713) page but it does not work with Windows 8.1 app apparently.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Windows Runtime Component? If it's an universal apps of course though.

Comment: What do you mean @KevinAvignon

Comment: Well, WinJS can be used in a c# windows phone application when using  a windows runtime component portable for universal apps. But there are some constraint such as having sealed classes. I was simply asking him if he thought of that option. The question is rather unclear so I was proposing an option that he might not have think of.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Is it from Xaml or the JavaScript? Does your HTML have a MyButton element? That InvokeScriptAsync looks fine: it is calling the JavaScript function "eval" with a script that eval runs to find the MyButton element on the page and wire up its click event to fire the WebView's ScriptNotify event.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT Thanks. The web page generated is not mine, so I have no control over any element name, the sample I gave is from a site, I changed the code to fit my need, but it won't work for my need. What I need is another way to inject JavaScript in the html content within the WebView.

Comment: The sample code injects the JavaScript in the second argument into the page and runs it. There isn't a better way. You'll need to change the injected JavaScript to do what you need. If you need help crafting the JavaScript you'll need to provide more information about what you need and where you're stuck in implementing it.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT Thanks! What I'm trying to do in my version of the code is to to return 'VideoClick' string and continue with the logic from WebView_ScriptNotify method. Problem is the execution never gets to WebView_ScriptNotify, my problem would be solved if execution could get there. Please see edited question for my implementation of WebView_ScriptNotify.

Answer (score 0):

Create the function in the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Head goes here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Body goes here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var signButton=document.getElementById("MyButton");
        if (signButton.addEventListener) {
            signButton.addEventListener("click", MyButtonClicked, false);
        } else {
            signButton.attachEvent('onclick', MyButtonClicked);
        }

        function MyButtonClicked(){
            window.external.notify('%%' + location.href);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And call it from your code: `await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
     { "MyButtonClicked();" });`

Comment: Thanks. The html generated is not mine, it's generated dynamically, so what I'm looking for is a way to insert codes in html I have no idea how it look like. So your answer won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JS has finished executing before attempting to call methods on it.
Use script debugging in Visual Studio in order to see the relevant errors.

for windows phone 8:
http://www.jayway.com/2014/03/10/windows-phone-8-native-and-javascript-interop/

for windows phone 8.1:
http://www.jayway.com/2014/08/27/webview-javascript-interop-woes-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app/